# barplot and plot on same graph - shift of x-axis

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to first plot a barplot, and then take its cumulative and plot it on the same figure (graph). Problem is that for plot command, the outcome is not centered on barplot values.

```
vec1 <- 1:10
vec2 <- vec1

for (ii in 2:length(vec1)) {
  vec2[ii] = vec2[ii-1] + vec1[ii]
}

p1 <- barplot(vec1)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(p1,vec2, axes=FALSE)
```

Comment: Also, try `vec2 <- cumsum(vec1)`.

Comment: hey.. thanks. The problem still is that the plot or line x-axis is not aligned w/ barplot (i.e; not centered on bars).

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the output is from this too.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `barplot` doesn't use integer values on the x-axis; it computes its own x values, I guess for scaling. To get the vector of points it's using so you can align other things with them, you need to pull them from the object returned by the call to `barplot`. Here's an example:

```
# make some toy data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(cat = LETTERS[1:3],
                 val = seq(3),
                 val2 = rpois(3, lambda = 5),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# now try adding val2 as points to a barplot of val1; as you found, the 
# points aren't centered
# over the bars like we want
barplot(df$val, ylim = c(0,7))
points(x = seq(3), y = df$val2, pch = 20, col = "red")
```

[image]

```
# try again, this time capturing the x values from a call to barplot and then
# using them in the call to points; this works
p <- barplot(df$val, ylim = c(0,7))
points(x = p, y = df$val2, pch = 20, col = "red")
```

[image]

Note that I had to set `ylim` in the initial call to `barplot` to make sure there was room for the points (or line).

Comment: thanks @ulfelder, using same logic can I create another y-axis on the left without having to modify bar's y-axis?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to do. Add a second y-axis? Modify the original one? If former, set `axes = FALSE` in your call to `barplot`, then use `axis` to draw the one you want. If latter, use `axis` to draw another one on the right. (I don't know how you could draw two on the same side without confusing the hell out of everyone.)